# How to call interface method from T parameter?

Tags: c#

Basically, what I'm trying to do is call an interface method within a class like this:

```
public class MongoConnection<T> where T: IMongoEntity
{
    public MongoConnection()
    {
        string connectionString = Configuration.Default.ConnectionString;

        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var server = mongoClient.GetServer();

        string DBName= "DBName";

        var DB = server.GetDatabase(DBName);

        MongoCollection collection = DB.GetCollection<T>(T.MyInterfaceMethod());
    }
}
```

The reason I'm doing

```
MongoCollection collection = BD.GetCollection<T>(T.GetCollectionName());
```

Instead of

```
MongoCollection collection = BD.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);
```

is because there won't be just one collection of that type, there will be multiple collections with the same structure.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: You need an instance of type `T` to call a method on it.

Comment: what is wrong with doing `typeof`?

Comment: What are you expecting to call with `T.GetCollectionName()`? Is it a method defined in `IMongoEntity`? Where is the implementation of that `GetCollectionName` you're trying to call?

Comment: Is the method you're trying call on the interface `IMongoEntity`?

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as a static interface in C#.